# Why injectivity class doesn't imply weakly reflective

Tags: category-theory, injective-module, locally-presentable-categories

In the snippet  below (taken from *Rosicky, Adamek: On injectivity in locally presentable categories*) in the context of locally presentable categories it seems that **injectivity class** doesn't imply **weakly reflective**. I'm interested why this reversion of the implication is not elementary true, i.e. why that factorization doesn't give us weak reflection, what's wrong with this intuition here ?

[image]

Comment: The definition of injectivity class does not have a factorisation condition.